# Issue with background image and margin top of a div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, background-image

I m trying to add a background on a Django form template. The issue is that if I have no margin top to the form, the background image is fine.
But whenever I try to add some margin, the background is split (between the top of my form and the top of my page)  :

[image]

Here is my .html:

```
 <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;                
            background-image: url("{% static 'places/img/banana_palms.jpg' %}");
            background-size: cover;
        }
    
        .registration-form-container {
            width: 400px;
            margin: auto;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .auth-box {            
            border: 3px solid lightblue;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding-top: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
            width:500px;
            margin:auto;
            background-color: white;
        }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    
        <div class="auth-box text-center mt-5">
            {% block content %}
            
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
   
</body>
</html>
```

How should I correct my code so the background display nicely?

Comment: Move `background-image` and `background-size` into the independent `body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `background-image` and `background-size` into the independent `body`.

Change this

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;                
    background-image: url("{% static 'places/img/banana_palms.jpg' %}");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

to this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;                
}
body {
    background-image: url("{% static 'places/img/banana_palms.jpg' %}");
    background-size: cover;
}
```